# Splitting array by spaces when there are 2 word strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically adding and removing checkboxes from a user created list. This works fine if the item put on the list is one word, but if it contains a space then it does not work. I understand why it wouldn't work but can't find how to do successfully splice the correct one from the array.

---

```
var boxCounter=0;
function addToCheckListNew(item){
    var newSet = '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="cbGroup' + boxCounter + '"></fieldset>';
    $('.cbDiv').append(newSet);
    var newBox = '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-' + boxCounter + '" id="checkbox-' + boxCounter + '" class="custom" /> <label for="checkbox-'+ boxCounter + '">'+item+'</label>';
    $(".cbGroup" + boxCounter).append(newBox).trigger('create');
    boxCounter++;
    $("#new-list-page-iteminput").val("");
    $("#new-list-page-itemlist").listview("refresh");
    currentList.push(item);
}

//Delete the selected checkboxes
function deleteCheckedListNew(){
    var checkedBoxes = $('form input:checked').parents('fieldset');
    for (var i=0;i<checkedBoxes.length;i++){
        var str = (checkedBoxes.text().trim());
            str = str.split(" ");
        var itemIndex = $.inArray(str[i],currentList);
        if(itemIndex!==-1){
            currentList.splice(itemIndex,1);
            checkedBoxes.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

The items put into the checkboxes are also stored in an array currentList, it is this that I am trying to remove them from. Removing the checkedboxes is fine.

Comment: Doesn't make sense getting text of fieldset which is what you are doing. Would make more sense to add a data attribute (simple fix not related to issue). What is impact if user does use 2 words or more...wouldn't that be considered unique? Can you provide demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u582wqzn/ My first time using jsfiddle and I couldn't get the deleting working the same as in my app. I hope it gives you a better understanding. Can you explain using a data attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about the value of the text at all.

You can simply use the display index of the items to delete from the stored index.

This is on the assumption that you won't have any sorting built in yet

I simplified this down to

```
//Delete the selected checkboxes
function deleteCheckedListNew() {
    var checkedRows = $('fieldset').has(':checkbox:checked');
    checkedRows.each(function(index){
        currentList.splice(index, 1)
    }).remove();

}
```

The next step I would suggest would be to use an array of objects for each item. Then you can assign a unique id to each which is far simpler to work with than parsing text.

Having an ID stored would then let you sort the list and still easily find the stored object using array filter() or other methods.

The array would then look more like

```
[
  {id:1, text:'eat lunch'},
  {id:2, text:'have a beer'}
]
```

The id would then also be put onto each row in the template making it easy to identify in array

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u582wqzn/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Hi, I think there is a problem as it removes the first option from the list. 
http://jsfiddle.net/u582wqzn/2/
I think using a list of more than one it removes the incorrect one from the array.

Comment: major overhaul...including stored objects  http://jsfiddle.net/u582wqzn/3/  Check console after removing for active array

Comment: As far as I can see it isn't removing any from the array? http://jsfiddle.net/u582wqzn/4/ I added an alert where it would be removing and it isn't? 
I understand the use of the id and I think you're right about that being the next step.

Comment: I forgot to save some changes when I posted that..had to go out ...here's updated http://jsfiddle.net/u582wqzn/5/

Comment: Works perfectly, maybe you want to edit your original answer, many thanks!